# Resize window on inner view addition/replacement (OSX, Cocoa)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window-resize

I have a window which is a placeholder for 2 different (in size) views (switching between the two).

I would like to resize the window whenever the view is switched.

This is what I came up with (this is called right after `replaceSubview` or `addSubview`):

```objc
- (void) resizeViews: (NSView*) customView{
  NSView* contentView = self.window.contentView;
  [customView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

  NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView);

  [contentView addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[customView]|"
        options:0
        metrics:nil
        views:views]];

  [contentView addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[customView]|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
}
```

This works only for the horizontal resize, vertically the window stays in its initial size (as set in the IB).

I have cleared all constraints from the window, without any luck.

Sorry if it's something obvious - I'm pretty new to Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something hacky, that is OK for now.

If someone is able to give a better solution, please, do so (I am not going to mark this as an answer for some time):

```c
- (void) onAddedView: (NSView*) newView{
  NSView* parentView = self.window.contentView;
  NSRect parentFrame = [self.window frame];
  CGSize newSize = [newView frame].size;
  int titlebarHeight = 22; // TODO: how to get this automatically?

  // resize the window (and reposition it) to fit the added view
  newSize.height += titlebarHeight;
  parentFrame.origin.y += parentFrame.size.height; // remove the old height
  parentFrame.origin.y -= newSize.height; // add the new height
  parentFrame.size = newSize;

  // center the added view
  [newView setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(
    (NSWidth([parentView bounds]) - NSWidth([newView frame])) / 2,
    (NSHeight([parentView bounds]) - NSHeight([newView frame])) / 2
  )];
  [newView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewMaxYMargin];

  // render changed view
  [self.window setFrame: parentFrame display: YES animate: NO];
}
```